# Error: not all code paths return a value

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio

I'm new to unity, so  I've been having problems with my code here:

```
public bool FindItem(GameObject item)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MyInventory.Length; i++)
    {
        if (MyInventory[i] == item)
        {
            //we found the item
            return true;
        }
        //if item not found
        return false;
    }
}
```

it shows this error : Assets/Script/Items/InventoryScript.cs(35,17): error CS0161: `InventoryScript.FindItem(UnityEngine.GameObject)': not all code paths return a value

I've been looking for answers on the internet but nothing seems to give me solution to this problem. so I was hoping you could help me, thanks again in advance ! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Not all code paths return a value" means that inside a function that's supposed to explicitly return something (ie. it's not `void` or a constructor/IEnumerator), the compiler found a way to hit the end of the function without a `return` statement telling it what it's supposed to return.

In this case, this happens if `MyInventory.Length` is zero. What happens:

- We enter the for loop and set `i = 0`
- We check the for loop's test, is `i < MyInventory.Length`? No, zero is not less than zero.
- Since we failed the test, we exit the for loop immediately, without visiting any of the code inside (not the `if MyInventory[i] == item`, not the `return true`, not the `return false`
- Since there's nothing after the for loop, we hit the end of the function, but the compiler doesn't know what `bool` value the function should return because we haven't encountered a `return` statement.

Thus, the error.

To fix this in this case, you want to move the `return false` statement *outside* your for loop to the end of the function. When you put it inside the loop, the loop will check whether the item is in `MyInventory[0]`, and if not, it will always return false before it gets a chance to check `MyInventory[1]`. You want to `return true` if and only if we get through the *whole* array and don't find the item, not immediately after a single mismatch.

Or you can replace the whole thing with

```
public bool FindItem(GameObject item) {
    return System.Array.IndexOf(MyInventory, item) >= 0;
}
```

`IndexOf` returns -1 if the item isn't found in the array.

As Mikael says, this is a pure programming question that doesn't need game-specific expertise, [so you can find answers to this elsewhere too](https://www.google.ca/search?q=not%20all%20control%20paths%20return%20a%20value).

Comment: thank you so much! :D what you said is totally correct, I double check my code and my return false is inside the for loop which is incorrect. you saved me DMGregory :D

Comment: @DMGregory is absolutely correct.  However, if you ever find yourself with a more complex function returning a bool (or returning anything, really) you should always have a default return value (for me that is often false) at the end.  Either by literally just having a return false; before your close bracket, or by setting a local `bool` variable that you set to a default at the top, then change as it hits any validations, and just `return _bool;` at the end.  I tend to use both a lot.

Comment: thanks, i'll try that also, so that I can practice more different ways of coding :)

Comment: @JesseWilliams myself, I'd recommend not adding a return statement where you don't expect one to be hit. That way, the compiler can alert you when your assumption is wrong. If you add a return statement "just in case," then when you later make a change that accidentally allows control flow to take a path you didn't expect, that new path gets accepted silently, without any reminder to double-check your assumptions. It might be more annoying that way, dealing with the occasional spurious error, but it helps keep you vigilant, and makes your intention/expectation explicit in the code. ;)

Answer (score 1):

If MyInvenyory does not contain any items the for loop will never execute, therefore it will skip the entire block of code.

To fix you should add a return statement after your loop.

Usually these kinds of questions are not encouraged since it's not directly related to gamedev and are more of a "debug my code" question, but since you are a new contributor I figured I might answer it anyway.

Comment: ok got it, thanks Mikael for all the help :) and I'll make sure that my questions next time will be related to gamedev :D